# Why is this not a proof of Schroeder-Bernstein?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, cardinals

We can show that if $f: A \rightarrow B$ is injective then $|A| \leq |B|$ and if $g: B \rightarrow A$ is injective then $|B| \leq |A|$ so $|A| = |B|$. By the definition of having equal cardinality, there exists a bijection between $A$ and $B$.

Whenever a textbook proves the theorem, however, a more complicated proof is shown. I must be missing something.

Comment: How is $\leq$ defined for cardinalities? And what is the proof that $(\kappa \leq \lambda) \land (\lambda\leq\kappa) \implies \kappa = \lambda$? Just because the notation looks like an order relation, doesn't mean it actually is one. There's something to be proved.

Comment: Oh... I see now, $|A| \leq |B|$ and $|B| \leq |A|$ implies $|A| = |B|$ *is* what we are trying to prove.

Comment: Schroeder Bernstein gets tagged calculus?